# Reducer state returns NaN value

Tags: redux, react-redux

I defined a reducer but it always returns `NaN` value instead of number.I defined a single store in `store.js` like `createStore(reducer,{},applyMiddleWire()`. Reducer is working but always return `NaN` value.

```js
import { INCREMENT, DECREMENT } from "./buttonAction";

const initialState = {
  counter: 1
};

const Count = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      state = {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };
      console.log("Number", state);
      break;
    case "DECREMENT":
      state = {
        ...state,
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };
      console.log("Number", state);

      break;
    default:
  }
  return state;
};

export default Count;
```

Comment: How are your dispatching actions ?

Comment: const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 console.log ("work dispatch");
  return {
    increment : () => { dispatch( increment() ) },
    decrement : () => { dispatch( decrement() ) }
  }
};

Comment: Show us `increment()` and `decrement()` please. I'm guessing you have a typo and the `action.type` is neither "INCREMENT" nor "DECREMENT". But that should give you the initialState... Hmm.

Comment: put console.log() in reducer and check what values coming from action. or you can check weather counter is number then return is NaN then not.

Comment: this is now working. but now {this.props.count} not working , or value from mapStateToProps not working

Comment: @AtikMahbub, can you post your code for your component?

Comment: I am getting the same error, Could you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the new state in SWITCH cases.

The point is that Redux state is not like React state.
When you changing React state, setState() change only specific part of state, while other state content remains untouched.

On the other hand, Redux wants you to always return a new state, a new object. Redux does not merge old state and new state like React do. So the answer is you need to create new object in every switch case and return it, and Redux will replace old state with new one.

```
switch (action.type) {
case "INCREMENT":
 return {
    ...state,
    counter: state.counter + 1
  };
  console.log("Number", state);
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same mistake, I think maybe your problem as others said is because payload is not defined into the Component(method-properties).

I solved and learn a little bit else with this mistake about lifecycle of redux.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-counter-03-xjqnq

```
increment = () => {
  // this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  this.props.dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT", payload: 5 });
};
decrement = () => {
  // this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
  this.props.dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT", payload: 3 });
};    enter code here
```